# append dataframe to excel with some part overwrite?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

My goal now is to append dataframe into an existed excel with date as index. Since sometimes i need to use the program several times a day ,I want overwrite that day when doing so.

For example, if I have 02-02 to 02-19 data and I want to 02-20 data just not overwrite any thing but if i have 02-02 to 02-19 data and now i got whole day 02-19 data, i want it just overwrite where 02-19 data start.

I already successfully write the dataframe to the excel, how can i set the startrow to fullfill my need

Answer (score 0):

use xlwings. You can find the cell no where your data ends in excel by using range.end('down'), which you can use as your start point for writing new dataframe .

Comment: but it's kinda of random thing. if it is just another new day it just append; but if it is repeated day it need to overwrite the data